# Will a GFCI still work correctly if a surge strip is plugged into it?

Tags: gfci

I have a GFCI in the bathroom and the two outlets are not enough.

I want to plug wall surge protector into the GFCI.

The result will be six outlets on the wall.

Will the GFCI still do its job for the devices that are plugged into the surge protector? I.e will the GFCI trip if the device falls in the water?

Research has given me conflicting answers.

Sound I just plug in a 1-to-3 multi-plug adapter i stead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That shouldn't be a problem. Normal leakage current to ground through the metal-oxide varistor (the component that provides surge protection) is much less than the amount which would trigger the ground fault interruptor.

The exceptions would be if an actual surge occurred and is suppressed, or if a previous surge burned out the MOV in a way that caused it to leak more.

Comment: Of course, if the surge suppressor leaks current to ground and this trips the GFCI, that does help kill off the surge before it gets to the protected appliances. Of course, I'm wondering what is being used in a bathroom that requires surge suppression...

Comment: I'more wondering what is being used in a bathroom that needs a power strip. Some folks do have everything from chargers to electric toothbrushes to Bluetooth speakers to whatever in their bathrooms... but if that's really what you need, you should consider putting more outlets where you need them.

Comment: (I'm considering adding a shelf in my bathroom with its own outlet, away from the plumbing but still on a GFCI,  for just this reason. )